# How to use sed to comment some lines in tex files (has "%" a particular meaning for sed ?)

Tags: beamer, automation, comments, recursion, terminal-output

I've been reading something in
[Most useful sed one-liners for TeX users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52752/most-useful-sed-one-liners-for-tex-users)
which is related to my problem, but albeit interesting, it is not what I need.

I have many tex (beamer class) files in subdirectories and I would like to comment some lines in each of them.

The purpose is to modify the preamble in order to compile the files to get the handouts as indicated in 
[Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) answer 45

In each file I have the following lines, which I comment in and out as needed.
The first one is to compile the beamer presentation while the others three are needed to compile for handouts

```
%here is some text, consistent in all the .tex files
%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
%
 \documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
 \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

The four lines above should be commented out and the some lines should be appended. The desired .tex file should contains the following

```
%here is some text, consistent in all the .tex files
\ifdefined\ishandout
 \documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\else
  \documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
\fi

%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
%
%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

Of course I could edit each file manually, but I would learn nothing.

I was  successful in inserting the lines from `\ifdefined` to `\fi`, by pasting them into a file (saved as insert.txt) and then sending in a terminal (debian wheezy) the following line

```
sed  -i "/^%here is some text, consistent in all the .tex files$/ r ../insert.txt" lesson_10.tex
```

I tested it only on one .tex file, and it works

To add the lines to each file in each subdir, I wrote this bash script

```
   for i in ??_lesson*/ 
    do
        if [ -d $i ] 
            then                
                cd $i
            THIS=$(ls lesson_??.tex) 
                 sed  -i "/^%here is some text, consistent in all the .tex files$/ r ../insert.txt" $THIS
            fi
        done
```

Now I need a sed command that change/replace the lines

```
\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

into/with

```
%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

I've read somewhere on the internet that sed process a line at time, so I tried this one.

```
sed "s/%\documentclass/%\documentclass/g" lesson_01.tex > checkthis.tex; head checkthis.tex
```

which returns

```
 \%documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \%documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
 \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

This other line was executed to check whether the problem was in the `s` or in the `g` part of the command

```
sed "s/%\documentclass/%\documentclass/g" lesson_01.tex > checkthis.tex; head checkthis.tex
```

which returns

```
\%
  oo[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 

 \%
   oo[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
 \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

It's evident that the "`%`" has a special meaning for sed, a meaning which I ignore.

I tried also some escaping characters before the `%`, but to no avail.
Googling around was of no help, I therefore decided to ask for a direct help here.

Comment: This seems to be a sed question rather than tex so I suspect it's off topic. % is not special to sed but \ is.

Comment: % is a special character for most shells, though, so if you pass it on the command line (rather than in a script), it may have unexpected effects. Try `sed -e 's/^\(\\documentclass\)/\%\1/' -e '/^\%\\documentclass/,/\\pgfuselayout/s/^\(.*pgf\)/\%\1/'` (not fully tested so don't use `-i` until you are sure).

Comment: For David. I was afraid of an OT myself too, but after googling extensively and not finding an answer, I decided to write here, where the problems with "%" are more probable to occur.

For cfr: the code works and the outcome is a s follows
{
%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
% \usepackage{pgfpages}
% \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

Comment: Sorry for the double post. I'm learning the local syntax for comments. Here a more readable version (I hope ...)

@cfr: the code works partially. Here's the outcome:

`%\documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, final, 10pt]{beamer} 
 \documentclass[xcolor={usenames, table, x11names}, handout, 10pt]{beamer} 
% \usepackage{pgfpages}
% \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]`
Only one occurrence of `\documentclass` has changed.

Could you be please so kind to bear with me a little more and explain briefly the syntax ?

Comment: @fcfr. The code works perfectly. It's my fault: I tested it on the wrong file. The first occurrence is `^\documentclass...` while the second one is not at the beginning of the line, but it have some spaces before !! 

`^   \documentclass...`