# Exclude everything from pdf document except images

Tags: graphics, pdf

is there any way to ONLY print out a pdf with all the image with the correct sizes as they appear in the single chapters/sections etc...? The reason is I want to only print out some pages (not the full article / thesis) containing only the images so that I can easily and cheap check wether the image quality is okay or not. Therefor, I don't need any tables, listings, TOC, the text etc...
Thanks!

**Edit**:
Embed code #1:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{flow1.pdf}
\caption{blaaaa}
\label{fig:blaaa}
\end{figure}
```

Embed code #2:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][asd]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=\scalefaktorDbl]{figs/asdasd.png}}\label{fig:LZKf1}}
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][asd234asd]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=\scalefaktorDbl]{figs/asdasd}}\label{fig:asd}}
\hfill\null
\caption{aasd}\label{fig:asd}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: are images inserted as floats?

Comment: There's a similar question here: [How do you print only the pages with figures on them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16096/2693). If this answers your question, we can close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Herbert: What do you exactly mean? The insert codes are edited into the first post above! @Alan: I'll read it now!

Comment: I think [How to retain figures only with captions in their original positions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15717/2975) is what you need. It uses 
`\usepackage[notext]{crop}`.

Comment: @Marc: use package `endfloat`, it puts all figures and tables at the end of the document. Then you can easily print only the pages with the images. after having done, delete the package and you'll get the original paper.

Comment: @Alan: It's not whats needed. I don't want ANY text (just to check the image quality by printing them all together and minimizing paper usage). I just want the images, perfect would be the automatic align of the images so that the taken space will be minimal e.g. by placing two pictures side by side if they fit... @Martin: I will read :)

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, but the figures are displayed ONE on each page and not really 'compressed' to minimize the number of needed papers..

Comment: @Marc: you can do a `\let\newpage\relax` before the images

Comment: @Herbert: `Error, \newpage undefined`. I put the code in the preamble! When I put it in front of the first figure, it doesn't work but no error occurs... Isn't there a more comfortable way?

Comment: See also [How can I ignore everything _except_ a specified environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-ignore-everything-except-a-specified-environment) which removes everything except figures and/or tables (or any other environment).

Comment: I don't see the concrete solutions implementation to my problem from the thread!?

Comment: @Marc: Try `\usepackage{xcomment}\xcomment{figure}` to ignore everything except `figure`s.

Comment: I'm always getting `error ! file ended while scanning use of \next` :(

Comment: @Marc: Looks like you have the `\end{figure}` inside another macro, don't you?

Comment: I just checked for something similar but unfortunatly I haven't!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try putting the following code, extracted from the package **syntonly**, just before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\font\dummyft@=dummy \relax
\dummyft@
\tracinglostchars=\z@
\count@\sixt@@n
\loop
\ifnum\count@ >\z@
\advance\count@\m@ne
\textfont\count@\dummyft@
\scriptfont\count@\dummyft@
\scriptscriptfont\count@\dummyft@
\repeat
\let\selectfont\relax
\let\mathversion\@gobble
\let\getanddefine@fonts\@gobbletwo
\pagestyle{empty}
\let\ps@fancy\ps@empty
\let\hline\relax
\newcolumntype{|}{}
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\makeatother
```

This should ignore all text, but include images, printing as many as possible on each page.

I've added some of the more frequent commands that need to be "neutralized".

## Alternative approach

Add the following to the preamble:

```
\newwrite\figurewrite
\immediate\openout\figurewrite=\jobname-figures.tex
\let\includegraphicsORI\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \immediate\write\figurewrite{\unexpanded{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}^^J}%
  \includegraphicsORI[#1]{#2}}
```

Compiling your document (say `thesis.tex` ) will write a file `thesis-figures.tex` containing the relevant `\includegraphics` commands and it's just a matter of adding a suitable preamble in order to compile this file.

Comment: Doesn't work :( There are many empty pages, often the images are printed as only one on a page and further the horizontal line from the chapter-headlines remain... The table-lines also remain!

Comment: Can you provide your preamble?

Comment: Thanks, the alternate way works. I'm getting one tex file which I can include testwise and print those pages out!

Comment: the alternative approach fails when the (yet uncommon) `\includesvg` is used (well, actually using the `*-figures.tex` file afterwards fails)

Answer (score 6):

```
\usepackage[active,floats]{preview}
```

in your document preamble should do the trick.  That puts out all the complete figures.  If what you are interested in are just the graphics inclusions, try

```
\usepackage[active,graphics]{preview}
```

instead.  If you leave out the `active` option, your document will appear unchanged, but you can use something like

```
pdflatex -jobname mygraphics '\PassOptionsToPackage{active}{preview}\input{myfile}'
```

in order to generate `mygraphics.pdf` with the extracted previews from `myfile.tex`.

Comment: this seems to have problems with the document class memoir, or at least i think so: with my (memoir-based) thesis only the bottom half of the images are printed on the very top and one per page; some images are printed two times.